# Android SDK environemnt path on windows 7

Tags: android, windows, sdk

I'm failing setting env. path on windows to android sdk, so I can use 'android' on command line, and also with Apache Cordova development.
I've tried probably any possible combination of following path - enclosed in question marks, deleted spaces in "Program Files (x86)" so it reads "ProgramFiles(x86)", added "tools", "tools\", "platform-tools", "tools\android.bat", etc. ... pretty much everything. But still cannot use 'android' on command line.

My ADK is installed in folder "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\"
Im running Windows 7 Professional 64bit

What I'm doing wrong? I've read all the available answers over internet and nothing work :(

Comment: post few lines of PATH from output of `set` on your command prompt. just want to see existing path format it uses.

Comment: These are my current paths they all work:

%ANT_HOME%\bin;"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin";C:\Users\Ales\AppData\Roaming\npm;"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin\"

Comment: just for testing, do you see android.bat when you enter `dir "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools"` ? if so, try `set PATH="c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools";%PATH%` , now run `android`

Comment: That worked @ashoke!
I run the 'dir<path>' command and then 'set' command and now I can use the android tool! Thank you!
So is this set for good, or do I have to set it every time before each session?

Comment: just add to your system environment PATH

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure what exactly I was doing wrong. Originally I was setting the PATH variable via dialog windows and couldn't make it work.
Then I set it directly from command line, set PATH="c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools";%PATH%, based on @ashoke suggestion from comment below my question, and it works since then.